# Date formatting issue in Apex

Tags: apex, date, formatting

I'm trying to format the date into specific format in Apex class, 
Desired result: 
2015-05-19T18:52:30.937-07:00

By using SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"); what I get is
2015-05-19T18:52:30.937-0700

I would like to know if the desired result (....-07:00 instead ....-0700) can be achieved without doing string manipulation, which is my last option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can achieve it by replacing the Z with  XXX.

```
Datetime sdf = Datetime.now();

system.debug(sdf.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX'));
```

The result was:

```
2015-05-20T20:28:23.203+02:00
```

This is documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#iso8601timezone)

Comment: Archieve haha. Somewhere between archive and achieve.